# Making product image in woocommerce invoice linkable

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

So, I am customizing woocommerce invoice email and here is a portion which displays product images in the email invoice:

```
if ( $show_image ) {
                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_thumbnail', '<img src="' . ( $_product->get_image_id() ? current( wp_get_attachment_image_src( $_product->get_image_id(), 'thumbnail') ) : wc_placeholder_img_src() ) .'" alt="' . __( 'Product Image', 'email-control' ) . '" height="' . esc_attr( $image_size[1] ) . '" width="' . esc_attr( $image_size[0] ) . '" style="vertical-align:middle; margin-right: 10px;" />', $item );
            }
```

I am trying to make this as a link to its product page such as the following:

```
  <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( $_product->id ) ); ?>">
```

However I am having a no luck. 
What would be the best way to modify the first code so that it can also get the product permalink?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

have you tried,

```
add_filter('woocommerce_order_item_thumbnail','reigel_woocommerce_order_item_thumbnail');
function reigel_woocommerce_order_item_thumbnail($item) {
   global $order;
   $_product = $order->get_product_from_item( $item );
   $item = '<a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink( $_product->id ) ) . '"><img src="' . ( $_product->get_image_id() ? current( wp_get_attachment_image_src( $_product->get_image_id(), 'thumbnail') ) : wc_placeholder_img_src() ) .'" alt="' . __( 'Product Image', 'woocommerce' ) . '" height="' . esc_attr( $image_size[1] ) . '" width="' . esc_attr( $image_size[0] ) . '" style="vertical-align:middle; margin-right: 10px;" /></a>';
   return $item
}
```

Add this to your functions.php. 
I have just coded it without testing, but this should work.. let me know if there's an error.

Comment: Hi Thank you for the reply. It crashed the site, I am going to check if there is any syntax error. But I think I understand the logic behind it and should make it work. Will let you know! =) Thanks Reigel'